# How to construct a neural network in R using caret

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

So I've been using the caret package to perform stuff like MLR, stepwise regression and random forest through the use of the train function. I've done this so that I can also do 10 fold cross validation 10 times, and I've done this by doing the following:-

```
library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = "10", repeats = "10", savePred = T)
cadets.mlr <- train(RT..seconds~., data = cadets, method = 'lm', trControl = ctrl)
```

From which I can then look at the predicted and observed values and plot them against each other and etc to see how accurate the model is. RT..seconds is the variable I want to model against 160 other variables for 180 different instances (i.e. 180 x 160 dataset).

I want to do the same thing but through the use of a neural network model. I want the learning ate to be 0.25 and momentum to be 50. I came across 'AMORE' and tried to do the same thing but using that instead by doing:-

```
cadets.nn <- train(RT..seconds.~., data = cadets, method = 'AMORE', trControl = ctrl)
```

But I keep getting the following message :-

```
Error in modelLookup(method) : value of model unknown
```

What am I doing wrong? And how do I go about tuning the parameters for Amore when I'm calling it through caret?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`AMORE` isn't currently wrapped by `train`. It has been requested previously, but it is difficult to abstract `AMORE`'s modeling code to work with the possible cases that people may want.

The neural network models that are wrapped by `train` can be found [here](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/Neural_Network.html). As of this writing there are 13 different neural network models available.

If none of those are what you would like and you are familiar with the `AMORE` package, you could write your own model code. See [this page](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/custom_models.html) for instructions and examples on how to do that.

Max

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the comment. Just tried to do it with neuralnet and got this message now:-
'cadets.nn <- train(RT..seconds.~., data = cadets, method = 'neuralnet', trControl = ctrl)
Error in length(y)/k : non-numeric argument to binary operator'
Do you know what the problem is?